# Disable past dates in javascript datepicker (asp.net)

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Can someone teach me how to disable dates in my js datepicker.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">



        $('.dateapick').fdatepicker({

            TodayHighlight: true,
            format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
            disableDblClickSelection: true,
            leftArrow: '<<',
            rightArrow: '>>',
        });
```

Here's my datepicker (JS)

```
<asp:Textbox  runat="server" ID="txtStartDate"   OnTextChanged="txtStartDate_TextChanged" onchange="subtractDate(this.Id)" placeholder="MM/dd/yyyy" AutoPostBack="true"  Enabled="true"  CssClass="form-control pickadate"></asp:Textbox>
```

and this is the front where i use my date.

Comment: whats `fdatepicker`?

Comment: This appears to be about the Foundation datepicker library. Is it? [edit] your question to let us know. If so, have you read [the documentation](http://foundation-datepicker.peterbeno.com/#docs)? There appears to be a `startDate` option...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `onRender` callback and based on your condition, return `disabled` or empty string

```
$('.dateapick').fdatepicker({

    TodayHighlight: true,
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
    disableDblClickSelection: true,
    leftArrow: '<<',
    rightArrow: '>>',
    onRender: function (date) {
        return condition ? 'disabled' : '';
    }
});
```